# Proof in vector analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis

Given $\mathbf{x}$^$\mathbf{a}$=$\mathbf{b-x}$

Prove

$(a^2+1)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{a}$^$\mathbf{b+b(a.b)a}$

I have been using this same dot product and crossproduct method, but don't get it.

The method I used is similar to a question that I recently posted here.

Comment: The link is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677267/solution-of-vector-equation